# Are the terms "n-ary function", or "multiary function", and "function of several variables" the same?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis

Are the terms "n-ary function", or "multiary function", and "function of several variables" the same?

I see that they are denoted by the same representation: e.g. f(x,y). But are they really the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meanings of the terms are essentially the same, but note that if you use the term "n-ary function" then you are declaring that "n" is the dimension of the domain. For example, "3-ary function" (which is somewhat awkward) says that it is a function of 3 variables. Even if you use the symbol "n" (rather than a specific number), you are committing yourself to letting "n" stand for the number of variables.  On the other hand, the phrase "function of several variables" leaves the number of variables unspecified and doesn't indicate any symbol (such as "n") that you will use to denote the number of variables.

In sum, they mean roughly the same thing, but "n-ary function" is a little more determinate.

**On Edit**. In the comments you retranslated the phrase as "multiary". In that case "multiary function" would be completely equivalent to "function of several variables." In English though, the phrase "multiary function" is rarely used.

The Wikipedia article on [Arity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) is a good guide to the usage.